# How to remove \n in every Arraylist item

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist, java-8

I extract some Data into a Arraylist. And in every Item there are several line breaks (\n) that I want to get rid of afterwards.

I´ve tried to do this:

```
public List<String> MemberIDList() {

    // Getting the ArrayList
    idList =  listProjection.getIDListOfMembers();

    for (int i = 0; idList.size() > i; i++) {
       String item = idList.get(i);
        item.replaceAll("\n", "");
    }

    return idList;
}
```

If I print that out on the console, it still contains all the line breaks:

```
The ID ...... (not null) 
     145     
     145
```

Thanks

EDIT: I also want to filter unnecessary whitespace. Is ther a better option than running the answers down below twice. There are spaces --------------------- this huge.

```
idList.replaceAll(item -> item.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", "").trim());
```

I got it :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
item.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

to

```
idList.set(i,item.replaceAll("\n", ""));
```

`item.replaceAll` doesn't modify the state of the `String` referenced by `item` (which is impossible, since `String` is immutable). It returns a new `String` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can replace all your method to be like so :

```
public List<String> memberIDList() {
    idList.replaceAll(item -> item.replaceAll("\n", ""));
    return idList;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `stream` and `map` them:

```
idList.stream()
    .map(str -> str.replaceAll("\n", ""))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will apply function `str -> str.replaceAll("\n", "")` to every element and collect them back to list. You can use this instead of your `MemberIDList` method.

P.S.: Method names are starting with lowercase in java.

Comment: Thanks I renamed my method. And will look up more about stream and map soon.